# How can I get rid of "-bash: ulimit: open files" when I open terminal on my mac

Tags: macos, bash, ulimit

Every time I open a new terminal, these messages show up:

```
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
-bash: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

I do modify ulimit before, but I've forgotten what I've done. So How can I fix this, please help. THX

---- update ----

I don't hava a .profile or .bashrc in my home dir. But I have a ~/.bash_profile and /etc/bashrc. And ~/.bash_profile looks like

```sh
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GF'
alias ll='ls -GFl'

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

/etc/bashrc looks like:

```sh
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
# Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    update_terminal_cwd() {
        # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
        # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
        # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

I don't see anything abount ulimit.

---- update ----

```
sudo ulimit -a -H
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) unlimited
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65532
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1064
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

sudo ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4864
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Comment: Look in your profile files: `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and find where you're trying to invoke `ulimit`.  You might need to look under `/etc`, but probably won't unless you went tinkering with profiles, etc, under there.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of `~/.bash_profile` and `set +x` to the bottom.  Create a new terminal window.  You should see a trace of the commands executed by your `~/.bash_profile`.  Spot where the error messages are generated.  If it comes before or after the trace code (you probably want to echo something like `echo "Trace off"` after the `set +x`), then you know that `~/.bash_profile` isn't generating the problem; it's another file.  You may have to read the [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) manual to find out which other files it reads.  Debug one file at a time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler neither /etc/bashrc or ~/.bash_profile :(

Comment: What are the values from `ulimit -a -H` and `ulimit -a`?  Add the outputs to the info in your question.

Comment: OK; the hard limits on the open files (`ulimit -n -H`) is 'unlimited' and the soft limit (`ulimit -n`) is '4864'; there's no obvious reason why the limit needs increasing.  Similarly with the maximum processes (hard: 1064; soft: 709).  Did the messages appear when you used the `set -x` and `set +x` debugging?  Did they appear before `/etc/bashrc` was run, or after it, or during it? Did they appear before, after or during the run of `~/.bash_profile`?  If they appeared 'during', then you should have information about which command was running (or which file).

Comment: If they appeared before or after, then that's important to know — and it is important to know which is applicable.  It controls what else we try looking at.  On the face of what I see, the only marginally suspicious item is `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`; could that program be generating that message?  It's unlikely, but you've not identified where the message is coming from yet, and until we know where it is coming from, it is hard to fix it.  I've not seen the problem when I work on a Mac.  That doesn't mean it isn't real.  It just means it isn't always a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72727/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-alexis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem. I've found that there are 3 profile files which OS X will load when opening a new Terminal, they are "/etc/bashrc", "/etc/profile", "~/.bash_profile". I found 2 lines about ulimit configiuring at the bottom of "/etc/profile". I delete these 2 lines and solve this problem.

Anyway, thanks to @Jonathan Leffler, you remind me to find what other profile causing this problem. THX XD